# How Android 2.2 interacting with Flash 10.1 (how to use flash from my app)?

Tags: android, flash, air, flashplayer-10, android-2.2-froyo

I'm searched adobe and android developers sites, but can't find any details on this.

Is it possible to use Flash as a part of my app? E.g. like a widget/GUI element? Or it's integrated in browser only and can't be simple accessible?

I know, Adobe AIR apps are supported as standalone .apk. So it must be some API/SDK (from Google) to connect with Flash player.

Is there any details, how to program it (more clear: launch swf from my app and interact with it)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Flash as a part
>   of my app? E.g. like a widget/GUI
>   element?

Not as a regular widget. Possibly it will work via a `WebView` widget, though that will not be known until phones get access to Android 2.2. Flash 10.1 only works on Android 2.2 and higher, and only on hardware (not the emulator) at this time.

> So it must be some API/SDK (from
>   Google) to connect with Flash player.

Not necessarily, particularly if Flash works with `WebView`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...
http://www.flashmobileblog.com/2010/03/12/flash-player-10-1-camera-support-phonegap/

Comment: Thank you, interesting article!